# Ayuda para poder sacar un texto en javascript, y convertirlo en un valor númerico con 2 decimales

Tags: javascript

Estoy en un proyecto y tengo que trabajar desde consola de Google Chrome porque no tenemos el código final, por ello debo hacerlo todo desde allí, con la consola logro saber cual es el texto que está en la web con este código que hace referencia a la clase padre y tal del texto

```
$(".col-sm-12.bg-white.content-list .col-sm-6.list-right .col-sm-4.price-car p").eq(0).text();
```

Ahora, me gustaría que el texto que me proporciona que es un precio con `$` , convertirlo en valor numérico sin perder el `$` y añadirle `2` `00` en decimales, algo así `$3,434.00` (Es americano, por ello, se usa la coma en lugar del punto para los miles). ya que ese valor es versátil, quiero que coja el texto directamente, porque cambiarlo es sencillo, pero necesito que coja ese texto sea cual sea y todo desde la consola de Google Chrome.

Comment: Si pones la pagina de ejemplo mucho mejor

Comment: Hola, no puedo por temas de política de privacidad....

Comment: Podrias poner aqui el valor que te sale con el selector??

Comment: "$3,114" esto me aparece al ejecutarlo

Comment: Y para añadir los dos 00 después del punto uso esta función, que en total quedaría así, pero me devuelve un NaN por no convertirse en un valor númerico 
function addZeroes( num ) {
   var num = Number(num);
   if (String(num).split(".").length < 2 || String(num).split(".")[1].length<=2 ){
          num = num.toFixed(2);
      }
   return num;
}
addZeroes($(".col-sm-12.bg-white.content-list .col-sm-6.list-right .col-sm-4.price-car p").eq(0).text());

Comment: @Zack Falta un poco de información para poder ayudarte, modifica el post, y arma una pequeña tabla, donde pongas de un lado el dato (como lo tenes en la página) y por el otro lado, la salida que esperas, de esa manera, va a ser más facil ayudarte

Comment: El dato es un precio, y se puede cambiar desde el CMS, por ello necesito un código de javascript que coja ese valor que es tipo texto y lo convierta en número para poder usarle esa función de addZeroes, el problema más grande es trabajar desde la consola de google chrome...

Comment: Y porque no concatenas ese valor que obtienes $(".col-sm-12.bg-white.content-list .col-sm-6.list-right .col-sm-4.price-car p").eq(0).text() + ".00";

Comment: @Zack como te decía arriba, si no amplias tu pregunta, es casi imposible contestarla

Comment: La respuesta de Jorge Bowen es estupenda, GRACIAS CRACK!!!!! te debo una, asunto resuelto :). pongo el resultado final para esto. :D

$(".col-sm-12.bg-white.content-list .col-sm-6.list-right .col-sm-4.price-car p").eq(0).text($(".col-sm-12.bg-white.content-list .col-sm-6.list-right .col-sm-4.price-car p").eq(0).text() + ".00");

Comment: Cómo puedo ponerte reputación Jorge Bowen? @JorgeBowen

Comment: Sin código, no deberían proporcionar ayudas. Nadie es adivino aquí.

Comment: Ahora si jajaja

Answer (score -2):

Y porque no concatenas ese valor que obtienes

```
$(".col-sm-12.bg-white.content-list .col-sm-6.list-right .col-sm-4.price-car p").eq(0).text() + ".00";
```